# Is there a "SnapToLevels" property in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

In ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF, I can set `SnapToLevels` as `True`, so when I zoom the map, it will snap to scale levels if the map contains cached layers.

However, I can't find anything like `SnapToLevels` in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET. Is there a property like that?

If so, will it work on touch device such as Surface Pro 3?  (`SnapToLevels` in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF doesn't work when pinching with fingers.)

I've posted this question to GeoNet, but no one has answered until now.

Answer (score 1):

There's an enhancement request submitted for this issue: 
[ENH-000085697: SnapToLevels property is not available in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net ]

Comment: Thank you. I will pay attention to the enhancement in next version.